No transfer fee for Mint Owner
is it possible to exempt the token mint owner from the transfer fee?
if not what happens when we create a market for such a token on Dex, Do all the rules apply while creating the market, like when we provide the token for Liquidity, will it also deduct the transfer fee?
How to avoid that?

Whenever transferchecked is called for your mint the transfer fees will be withhold in the token account. But you can collect the tokens. So that should not be a big problem.
Here is a guide on that extension: https://solana.com/de/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-fee
And a video walkthrough: https://youtu.be/isFB5Tk6kPo?si=armdma6p2s4bKAFG

Thanks for your response, I understand the functionality of the Transfer fee, I just wanted to provide 100% of the token as liquidity when creating a pair. and Transfer fee to be applied right after I provide liquidity for it.
can the transfer fee be charged not with a transfer fee extension but rather using a transfer hook and writing a program to deduct some amount of tokens as fee?

In a transfer hook you can not change the passed in token accounts so I think you would need another solution. You can adjust the transfer fee after the liquidity is provided. Would that be an option? The cli function is set-transfer-fee i think.
